# Generating API Keys for an App Engine Backend

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an Android/iOS SDK that communicates with my backend via App Engine and Cloud Endpoints. I want to restrict access to my backend to developers that have created an account and generated an "API key" (in quotes because I am unsure what form it takes) to interact with my backend. I also want to keep track of which developer/app a request originated from, so I want a unique key for each developer.

Cloud Endpoints uses SSL, so can I simply generate a public and private API key as cryptographically secure random number and include these in the body of my request, to be authorized by my backend, which has these keys stored somewhere?

Again, I'm not interested in protected the request in its transit from client to my server, but rather authorizing the "user" (in this case, the developer). Would appreciate any feedback/insights/best practices for this scenario.

--

Edit: not sure if code will really help, but here is a stripped down version of my API.

```
public class MyApi {

  public MyApi() {

  }

  public CEDataTransformResponse transformData(CEDataTransformRequest request) throws UnauthorizedException {

    CERequestHeader header = request.getHeader();
    if (header == null) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException("Missing header.");
    }
    authorizeToken(header.getToken());

    CEDataTransformResponse out = processRequestBody(request.getBody());

    return out;
  }

  private void authorizeToken(CEApiToken token) throws UnauthorizedException {
    // Current way
    if (!token.getToken().equals(Constants.TOKEN)) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException("Unauthorized");
    }

    // Future way?
    String apiKey = token.getApiKey(); String apiSecret = token.getApiSecret();
    if !((mDatastore.containsKey(apiKey)) && (mDatastore.getValue(apiKey) == apiSecret)) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException("Unauthorized");
    }
  }
}
```

In the "future way", imagine `mDatastore` is some wrapper around a key-value store. I'm ignoring any hashing I would do.

I've looked into generating Client IDs in the Cloud Platform developers console, but this is too manual; this needs to happen programmatically when a new developer signs up/downloads my sdk/requests the key.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few points here.

1. While using SO, you should post code. Questions need to take the form of specific programming questions, and 9 times out of 10, that means posting your code.
2. No matter what, you need to show what you have done, what research you have performed, and what is your current error/roadblock. Please keep that in mind when posting questions, as as such, update your current question.
3. In regards to your question, your "API key" is actually just a "User". Create a login system, and authorize using OAUTH. You can track the user and give any credentials to them you want. As well, OAUTH should have the added benefit of protecting data while in transit.

Comment: Added some code above, but not sure it'll make anything clearer. As I stated above, I looked into client IDs via the developer console, but that doesn't work for me. I also looked into oAuth, though I think it is not necessary because I will own the login system, so it seems redundant to generate an access token on login and then use that token to hit the backend when I can just authorize directly on some login on the backend, as I suggested above.